# How to make composite foreign key for sqlite database in drizzle schema?

Tags: javascript, sqlite, database-design, drizzle, drizzle-orm

Below are the schema I want to implement (if that makes sense)

```
CREATE TABLE parent_table (
    parent_id1 INTEGER,
    parent_id2 INTEGER,
    data TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY (parent_id1, parent_id2)
);

REATE TABLE child_table (
    child_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    parent_id1 INTEGER,
    parent_id2 INTEGER,
    child_data TEXT,
    FOREIGN KEY (parent_id1, parent_id2) REFERENCES parent_table(parent_id1, parent_id2)
);
```

How to implement this in drizzle?

Comment: Are you wedded to this schema? It may be better to add a separate `parent_id` auto-increment column and use that as the primary key and reference in the foreign key.

Comment: I believe that the manual covers everything at https://orm.drizzle.team/docs/indexes-constraints in the Foreign Key section (and scroll down to where it says *"To declare multicolumn foreign keys you can use a dedicated foreignKey operator:"*); including MySQL and SQLite equivalents.